# cloning drives to correct RAID 10 failure

Tags: raid, clone, software-raid

I don't type questions like this very often, so I apologize if I could have made it clearer.

I have 4 HDD slots in which I had a RAID 10 array setup. It is a motherboard software RAID so clonezilla does not detect the array. Something happened which knocked out the first two drives; I might be a culprit. Now my RAID 10 is just a RAID 0. I need assistance going from 0 to 10 with the least pain necessary.

I also might have accidentally formatted both the drives which fell out of the array thinking that might fix things. So now I need to get that data back over on the two empty drives from the RAID 0 pair that is currently fine and fulfilling my computing needs.

What software can I use to clone my source drive(s) over my target drive(s). It doesn't matter to me if I am cloning one physical device over another (one at a time) or the raid pair over the other two in which case I probably will need to cross my finger and hope it works.

I have access to ubuntu, linuxmint, fedora, and windows 7. I really don't want to compile anything. Is there anything I can do to get the job done?

Comment: What's wrong with using the bios raid utility to add the two drives to the array and rebuild?

Comment: @psusi I haven't seen any options to do any such thing in the RAID utility

Comment: It should have an option to add a drive to the array and/or rebuild it... that's kind of the whole point of raid.

Comment: @psusi Well I haven't seem any. There were two options to create a new array or view an already defined one. I don't know how to do anything like what you're talking about with rebuilding or adding to an array. I am just using the firmware on my ASUS mobo for my RAID configurations